# Chainable Razor Helper API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I want a suite of Razor helpers for generating form inputs.  I want the helpers to have a chainable API, allowing the form inputs to be called from multiple contexts (within a form group, as standalone inputs), and with several customizable attributes (value, placeholder, class, etc).  I do **not** want to implement 100+ method overloads to achieve my goals.

Example API:

```
    @Html.TextField("Test Text")
    @Html.TextField("PhoneNumber").Placeholder("555-555-5555")
    @Html.TextField("FirstName").Value("Gilbert")
    @Html.TextField("LastName").Value("Grape").Placeholder("Last Name Here")
```

I have an implementation that supports this syntax but I'm afraid it relies on a hack in order to function.  Please examine this implementation and tell me if I am making a mistake.  The part of interest is in `ChainableTextField.ToString()`:

```
public static class HtmlFormExtensions
{
    public static ChainableTextField TextField(this HtmlHelper html, string name)
    {
        return new ChainableTextField(html.ViewContext.Writer,name);
    }

    public class ChainableTextField
    {
        private readonly TextWriter _writer;
        private readonly TagBuilder _tagBuilder;

        public ChainableTextField(TextWriter writer, string name)
        {
            _writer = writer;
            _tagBuilder = new TagBuilder("input");
            _tagBuilder.Attributes["name"] = name;
            _tagBuilder.Attributes["type"] = "text";
        }

        public ChainableTextField Value(string value)
        {
            _tagBuilder.Attributes["value"] = value;
            return this;
        }

        public ChainableTextField Placeholder(string placeHolder)
        {
            _tagBuilder.Attributes["placeholder"] = placeHolder;
            return this;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            _writer.WriteLine(_tagBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

The "hack" is

```
public override string ToString()
{
    _writer.WriteLine(_tagBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
    return "";
}
```

Is it bad practice to do this?  Am I going to have trouble down the road if I use this technique?

Comment: Which bit in particular is the hack?

Comment: I updated the question with a clarification of what I consider the hack

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`IHtmlString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihtmlstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) interface is specifically designed for this purpose. So you'd rather have your `ChainableTextField` class implement this interface instead of overriding the `ToString` method. This way you no longer need to be passing a `TextWriter` to the constructor of this class.

Comment: So, with an IHtmlString, I can generate a `ChainableTextField` and then optionally alter it (with `Placeholder()` or `Value()`) before finally displaying it?

Comment: Ahh, I can indeed!  Thank you.  I suspected that there was something like this